# number duplicate entries in a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a below table.

| cid | oid | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:16.235 |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:21.549 |
| 1 | 23 | 2020-07-27 13:00:18.446 |
| 1 | 34 | 2021-08-17 09:42:20.778 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:37:53.340 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:07.564 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:28.201 |
| 1 | 09 | 2022-08-03 10:32:24.202 |

I tried the below query.

```
select
   cid,
   oid,
   dense_rank() over (partition by oid order by order_date) as oid_history   
from 
    master.t1
where 
    cid = 1
order by 
    order_date asc;
```

Got the below output.

| cid | oid | order_date | oid_history |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:16.235 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:21.549 | 2 |
| 1 | 23 | 2020-07-27 13:00:18.446 | 1 |
| 1 | 34 | 2021-08-17 09:42:20.778 | 1 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:37:53.340 | 1 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:07.564 | 2 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:28.201 | 3 |
| 1 | 09 | 2022-08-03 10:32:24.202 | 1 |

Expected output.

| cid | oid | order_date | oid_history |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:16.235 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:21.549 | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | 2020-07-27 13:00:18.446 | 2 |
| 1 | 34 | 2021-08-17 09:42:20.778 | 3 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:37:53.340 | 4 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:07.564 | 4 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:28.201 | 4 |
| 1 | 09 | 2022-08-03 10:32:24.202 | 5 |

Thank you:)

Comment: in your sample table the column order_date is absent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the expected output, it looks like a use-case for `conditional_change_event`.

```
with data (cid, oid, order_date) as (
 select * from values
 (1,12,'2020-07-01 13:19:16.235'::date),
 (1,12,'2020-07-01 13:19:21.549'::date),
 (1,23,'2020-07-27 13:00:18.446'::date),
 (1,34,'2021-08-17 09:42:20.778'::date),
 (1,55,'2022-08-01 13:37:53.340'::date),
 (1,55,'2022-08-01 13:38:07.564'::date),
 (1,55,'2022-08-01 13:38:28.201'::date),
 (1,09,'2022-08-03 10:32:24.202'::date)
 )select *,
 1+conditional_change_event (oid) over (order by cid) as oid_history
from data;
```

| CID | OID | ORDER_DATE | OID_HISTORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 2020-07-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | 2020-07-27 | 2 |
| 1 | 34 | 2021-08-17 | 3 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 55 | 2022-08-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 9 | 2022-08-03 | 5 |

Comment: `From the expected output, it looks like a use-case for conditional_change_event.` Agreed. That's a perfect use case for it.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this one?

```
select
   cid,
   oid,
   order_date,
   dense_rank() over (partition by cid order by oid) as oid_history   
from 
    mytable -- master.t1
where 
    cid = 1
order by 
    order_date asc;

+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
| CID | OID |       ORDER_DATE        | OID_HISTORY |
+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
|   1 |  12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:16.235 |           1 |
|   1 |  12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:21.549 |           1 |
|   1 |  23 | 2020-07-27 13:00:18.446 |           2 |
|   1 |  34 | 2021-08-17 09:42:20.778 |           3 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:37:53.340 |           4 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:07.564 |           4 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:28.201 |           4 |
+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Based on your new question, here is the answer:

```
select
   cid,
   oid,
   order_date,
   CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT( oid ) over (partition by cid order by ORDER_DATE ) + 1 as oid_history   
from 
    mytable -- master.t1
where 
    cid = 1
order by oid_history;

+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
| CID | OID |       ORDER_DATE        | OID_HISTORY |
+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
|   1 |  12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:16.235 |           1 |
|   1 |  12 | 2020-07-01 13:19:21.549 |           1 |
|   1 |  23 | 2020-07-27 13:00:18.446 |           2 |
|   1 |  34 | 2021-08-17 09:42:20.778 |           3 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:37:53.340 |           4 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:07.564 |           4 |
|   1 |  55 | 2022-08-01 13:38:28.201 |           4 |
|   1 |  09 | 2022-08-03 10:32:24.202 |           5 |
+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------+
```

I didn't want to update my answer (my comment explains the reason) but Pankaj already answered, so I also had to share my answer. Now, I'm waiting for another hidden requirement to modify my answer.

Comment: Added the date column.

Comment: @Kushal, in this case, you don't care about the date column because you rank "2020-07-01 13:19:16.235" and "2020-07-01 13:19:21.549" as 1. So the above query is still correct. You may want to change the ORDER BY part, because you wanted to use ORDER BY order_date;

Comment: it doesn't give the right output.

Comment: @Kushal I added the missing column, and shared the output. Can you compare it with the desired result?

Comment: I checked, and the order in which the numbering is being assigned in the output is incorrect in my actual data as the order created on 1st Aug is being numbered as 2 instead of 4. FYI: here i have added the dummy values instead of real-time data :D In my opinion we must not order by oid in dense_rank as the next oid assigned(after order is created) may be lesser then 55 ex"09" as it is auto generated.

Comment: I agree with the above-attached data your solution works. But, in my real data, i have an order id (oid = 09)created on '2022-08-03 10:32:24.202'. this latest order is being numbered as 1. I have updated the table now

Comment: @Kushal with a small change, my query provides the exact output, but I'm spectical to share any updates on this because I don't know if you will come up with another "but I need something I didn't say"...